# How to grep a string in a directory and all its subdirectories?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, centos

How to grep a string or a text in a directory and all its subdirectories'files in  LINUX ??

Comment: Are you going to provide any feedback on the problems you encountered with `grep -r` or `grep -R`?  Did you check the man page for `grep` on your machine?  Did you remember to enclose the regex (string or text) in single quotes if it contains any metacharacters?

Answer (score 485, accepted):

If your grep supports `-R`, do:

```
grep -R 'string' dir/
```

If not, then use `find`:

```
find dir/ -type f -exec grep -H 'string' {} +
```

Answer (score 55):

```
grep -r -e string directory
```

`-r` is for recursive; `-e` is optional but its argument specifies the regex to search for.  Interestingly, [POSIX `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) is not required to support `-r` (or `-R`), but <s>I'm practically certain that System V `grep` did, so</s> in practice they (almost) all do.  Some versions of `grep` support `-R` as well as (or conceivably instead of) `-r`; AFAICT, it means the same thing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure SVR3.2 and SVR4 grep did not, as I worked on OS development for SYSV products during that time frame, and I had a rgrep shell script to wrap it at the time.  I don't have one up any more to test on though.

Comment: `-R` follows symlinks, which you may or may not want